# How to use the Selection Reticle in CesiumJS

Tags: cesiumjs

In any of the Cesium sandcastle examples with entities, clicking an entity shows a green square reticle type thing.

My question is, what is it? I want to implement something that behaves similarly but can't find anything about it in the code base or the documentation.

Note: I have disabled the selection widget in my application.

You can see the reticle thing I am talking about in the attached photo.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You mention:

> Note: I have disabled the selection widget in my application.

I'm guessing you have a typo or something, because that green reticle is indeed the `SelectionIndicator`.  It can be disabled by setting a constructor option on the `Cesium.Viewer`, namely:

```
var viewer = new Cesium.Viewer('cesiumContainer', {
    selectionIndicator: false
});
```

Check your code to see if you really set this option correctly in the constructor.

After the `viewer` is constructed, it's a bit late to try to turn it off, since it binds into events generated by `viewer.selectedEntity` changing values.  By default, the `selectedEntity` gets the `SelectionIndicator` unless the viewer was constructed without one.

Comment: I am using `selectionIndicator: false` when creating the viewer instance. I do not want the default behavior, I would like to re-create the green reticle however.

Comment: Do you think that is possible?

Comment: Oh, I just inspected the page and realized that it is a svg that lives outside of the cesium canvas and is translated around to "stay in place".